# How do I write SQL with format 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN ( SELECT ... )' in rails class model scope?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I write SQL with

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE tableA.col1 IN (
  SELECT tableB.col2 
  FROM tableB
)
```

in Rails model scope?

Currently, I have a SQL like this in ruby model file as class method:

```
class Book
  def self.select_list_for_current_project_fund_schemes_sponsor_name
    Books.connection.select_all('
      SELECT book.name, book.name 
      FROM BOOK b
      WHERE b.b_pk IN (
        SELECT s.b_fk
        FROM STORE s
      )
    ').rows
  end
end
```

It works, and produce the output I want:

```
Book.select_list_for_current_project_fund_schemes_sponsor_name
=> [[book_name1, book_name1], [book_name2, book_name2], [book_name3, book_name3]...]
```

But I want to write it in scope so it is consistent with other code.

How do I write the SQL above using ActiveRecord 'where' method in the class model scope?

I want something like this in the class's model file:

```
class Book
  scope :books_in_store_that_exist, -> { where(magic_sql_wrapped_in_ruby_here) }

  # more code here...
end
```

**Note: I don't have model for Store, I only have Book model.**

In other words, I want to be able to achieve the same output by writing

```
Book.books_in_store_that_exist.select(:name).map {|b| [b.name, b.name]}
=> [[book_name1, book_name1], [book_name2, book_name2], [book_name3, book_name3]...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you just need to add a inner join

```
class Book
  scope :books_in_store_that_exist, -> { joins("INNER JOIN stores ON books.b_pk = stores.b_fk") }
end
```

Now you can use it to chain it.

```
Book.books_in_store_that_exist.select(:name).map { |b| [b.name, b.name] }
#=> [[book_name1, book_name1], [book_name2, book_name2], [book_name3, book_name3]...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however I realise I have duplicate resulting rows, do you happen to know how to get rid of the duplicates? I was looking up Google and saw `DISTINCT` but it seems to work on `SELECT` and not `JOIN`.

Comment: Try this `Book.books_in_store_that_exist.distinct(:name).select(:name).map { |b| [b.name, b.name] }`

Comment: For future people, you can also use `where` like this: `scope :books_in_store_that_exist, -> { where("b.b_pk IN (SELECT s.b_fk FROM STORE s))" }`